# Webpack 2 and typeahead.js

Tags: webpack, requirejs

Hi I'm trying to migrate a RequireJS app to Webpack. All my js files are included in the project I'm not using anything from `node_modules`. Why is it trying to include from there? This is a web project that will only be used in a web browser and does not use browserify.

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'private/application/controllers/'
        ],
        alias: {
            typeahead: 'system/js/jquery.typeahead.min',
            bloodhound: 'system/js/bloodhound.min',
            ...
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /typeahead/, loader: 'imports-loader?jquery' },
            { test: /bloodhound/, loader: 'imports-loader?typeahead' },
            ...
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin( /^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/ )
    ],
    target: 'web',
    entry: {
        app: 'system/js/app',
        module: 'system/js/module',
        ...
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'amd',
        filename: '[name].min.js',
        path: __dirname + 'public/files/cache'
    }
};
```

The error I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'setimmediate' in '/Users/name/Sites/revamp/node_modules/timers-browserify'
 @ ./node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js 51:0-23
 @ ./private/application/controllers/system/js/jquery.typeahead.min.js
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your loaders search the entire project folder for those files.
You could try adding `exclude: /node_modules/` to each loader.

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /typeahead/, loader: 'imports-loader?jquery', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /bloodhound/, loader: 'imports-loader?typeahead', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            ...
        ]
    },
```